# Sharepoint online - private folders for accounts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, microsoft365

I have a SharePoint online site with different users added (read-only). Everyone has a folder where they can store their personal documents.

Is there any way to make each account see only their own folder with their documents when they enter SharePoint online site? I can´t figure out the right way to do it; I need it to be some sort of personal storage.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the folders permissions to make each folder only access to their own account. You could refer to this article to manage permissions for folders:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-sharing-onedrive-or-sharepoint-files-or-folders-or-change-permissions-0a36470f-d7fe-40a0-bd74-0ac6c1e13323